# Trying to get the top two records from table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the first record the first time and then the second record with the second query. I am using those two queries but they return the same thing:

```
SELECT M.CODE,
ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
SELECT TOP 1 PRICE AS PRICE FROM MTRLINES ML WHERE ML.MTRL=M.MTRL AND FINDOC IN (SELECT FINDOC FROM FINDOC WHERE SOSOURCE=1251 AND FPRMS IN (1,2)) ORDER BY FINDOC DESC ) T
ORDER BY PRICE),0) AS B
FROM MTRL M
WHERE M.SODTYPE=51 AND M.COMPANY=1 AND M.CODE=:kod_an
ORDER BY M.CODE
```

This gets the first record then trying to execute this query to get the second record:

```
SELECT M.CODE,
ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
SELECT TOP 2 PRICE AS PRICE FROM MTRLINES ML WHERE ML.MTRL=M.MTRL AND FINDOC IN (SELECT FINDOC FROM FINDOC WHERE SOSOURCE=1251 AND FPRMS IN (1,2)) ORDER BY FINDOC DESC ) T
ORDER BY PRICE),0) AS B
FROM MTRL M
WHERE M.SODTYPE=51 AND M.COMPANY=1 AND M.CODE=:kod_an
ORDER BY M.CODE
```

But it returns the same result. I am still learning thanks!

Edit:

Just a simple illustration just to get the idea: User passes the variable `:kod_an`

I have two tables for example:

```
|MTRL|  CODE  |
---------------
| 1  | 080109 |
| 2  | 085145 |
| 3  | 084141 |


|MTRL|  PRICE  | FINDOC |
-------------------------
| 1  |  4.95   | 12345  |
| 1  |  4.50   | 23421  |
| 1  |  3.90   | 23499  |
```

So the user is searching for the code (:kod_an) the last two prices (in our example `:kod_an=080109`). My output should be `3.90` in the first query and `4.50` in the second query. Findoc should have descending order, in order to select the first time the last one and the second time the second one from the top this time!

To conclude my queries is showing 3.90 in both situations. I do not know why...

Comment: sample data and expected output would be real helpful but i'm 99% sure that query is over complicated. You're getting one record because of the `ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 *` in both queries. This will limit it to 1 record.

Comment: Rather than dumping these queries on us, can you edit your question and show us sample table data along with the output you want?

Comment: Investigate joins. I'm pretty sure this is what you are trying to accomplish in a round about way.

Comment: why did you make the code unreadable again? :( Look into `row_number() using a cte`

Comment: I hope it makes more sense now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

```
select 
    sub.code
  , sub.price
from (
    select 
        m.code
      , ml.price
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by m.code, order by price)
    from mtrl m
      inner join mtrlines ml
        on m.mtrl = ml.mtrl
    where m.code=:kod_an
  ) sub
where rn in (1,2)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VQIGT77173

returns:

```
+---+-------+-------+
|   | code  | price |
+---+-------+-------+
| 1 | 80109 |     4 |
| 2 | 80109 |     5 |
+---+-------+-------+
```

You could repeat the above once for `rn = 1` and again for `rn = 2` if you want two results sets for some reason.

Comment: Did you check the revised question?

Comment: @F.Mysir Revised my answer

Comment: Yours was giving me a time out error. And as I said I wanted FINDOC with descending order. But overall thank you for the direction ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of SqlZim I have achieved what I was looking for:

```
SELECT 
        SUB.CODE
      , SUB.PRICE
FROM (
        SELECT 
              M.CODE
              , ML.PRICE
              , rn = row_number() over (PARTITION BY M.CODE ORDER BY FINDOC DESC)
        FROM  MTRLINES ML
              INNER JOIN MTRL M
                    ON M.MTRL = ML.MTRL  AND FINDOC IN (SELECT FINDOC FROM FINDOC WHERE SOSOURCE=1251 AND FPRMS IN (1,2)) 
              WHERE  M.SODTYPE=51 AND M.COMPANY=1 AND M.CODE=:kod_an
      ) sub
WHERE rn IN (1,2)
```